# CouchDB shuts down for no apparent reason

Tags: centos, couchdb

My CouchDB server (on a CentOS 4 installation) sometimes shuts down without my knowing.

- I'm sure the server doesn't restart (looking at the uptime).
- I've looked in the logs (both the var/log directory and the couchdb.stderr log file, the log severity is set to info, which would show errors too), but nothing indicates that a shutdown was issued, let alone the process doing so.
- Lastly, since the server isn't being used in a production environment yet I doubt that it is a memory/buffer issue.

How can I log how and why the server is shut down?

Comment: Are you on EC2? I have seen similar bugs on EC2 with CouchDB and I have heard others mention it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try use strace/gdb or setup debug level(http://beauty-of-code.de/2009/11/setting-debug-level-in-couchdb/).